# I get errors when i add this ActionListener

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I have below code:

```
 <h:commandButton type="submit" action="#{clController.getPaymentByMonth(clController.type)}"  id="stateInfo"  value="Show Monthly "  >
  <f:actionListener binding="#{clController.getTotal(clController.type)}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

When i add  `<f:actionListener binding="` this  it gives below errors:

```
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ActionListenerHandler$LazyActionListener.processAction(ActionListenerHandler.java:112)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
```

This my getTotal function:

```
 List<CustomerPayment> total = null;
        try {
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT SUM(amount) from CustomerPayment where DATE like '%"+year+"' GROUP BY type");
            total = (List<CustomerPayment>) q.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return totalDataTable = new ListDataModel(total);
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: What i want is to call two methods when i click commandButton

Comment: You've missed the top off your stack trace. The "... at ..." lines come after the first, all-important line that describes the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the value of `actionListener`'s `binding` attribute - it should point to an object implementing the `ActionListener` interface - not a method call as is in your case.

From the JSF spec:

> Value binding expression that evaluates to an object that implements javax.faces.event.ActionListener.