# Why i cannot call the function?

Tags: java, jsf

```
 <f:actionListener binding="#{clController.getTotal((clController.year))}" />
```

I try to call clController.getTotal((clController.year)) function but i think there's a problem.

why ? How can i call function with actionListener

i put this actionListener

```
<h:commandButton type="submit"  action="#{clController.getPaymentByMonth(clController.year)}"  id="stateInfo"  value="Show Monthly "  >

                            </h:commandButton>
```

between this

```
May 1, 2013 4:27:42 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/customerPaymentPlan.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: /customerPaymentPlan.xhtml @84,220 onclick="#{clController.getTotal((clController.year))}": Unable to find method [getTotal] with [1] parameters
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2350)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderOnclick(RenderKitUtils.java:442)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ButtonRenderer.encodeBegin(ButtonRenderer.java:166)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
```

Comment: What makes you think there's a problem? In other words, what's actually happening? Unrelated, but why the extra parens?

Comment: What problem are you seeing?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question over and over. Your question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315341/i-get-errors-when-i-add-this-actionlistener

Answer (score 0):

The value of a `binding` attribute has to be an object implementing `ActionListener` interface not a method call.

So you would have:

`<f:actionListener binding="#{clController.totalListener}" />`

and the `totalListener` has to implement the mentioned interface.

Another possibility to call the method would be like this:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" action="#{clController.getPaymentByMonth(clController.year)}" actionListener="#{clController.getTotal(clController.year)}" id="stateInfo" value="Show Monthly " />
```

- so not using the f:actionListener tag

Comment: so how can i call method?

Comment: i need to clController.getTotal() method

Comment: so call the method in the interface implementation  `public void processAction(ActionEvent actionevent){ clController.getTotal();}`

Comment: or there is another way - see my edited answer