# Multiple actionlisteners in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use multiple action listener to set state of two backing beans before further processing

**1st way:**

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" >
   <f:attribute name="key" value="#{node.getIdTestGroup()}" />
   <f:actionListener binding="#{testController.nodeListener}" />
<f:actionListener binding="#{testDeviceGroupController.prepareCreate}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

It give an exception:

WARNING: /testGroup/List.xhtml @26,88 binding="#{testController.nodeListener()}": Method nodeListener not found
javax.el.ELException: /testGroup/List.xhtml @26,88 binding="#{testController.nodeListener()}": Method nodeListener not found

**2nd way:**

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" >
    <f:attribute name="key" value="#{node.getIdTestGroup()}" />
    <f:actionListener binding="#{testController.nodeListener(event)}" />
    <f:actionListener binding="#{testDeviceGroupController.prepareCreate(event)}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Event is null on the nodeListener and prepareCreate methods

How to do it correct?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see you facilitate the traditional approach of *guess-how-it-works-using-bare-intuition-and-random-associations-then-act-surprised* :-)

`f:actionListener` only lets you add a whole object as an observer, not an arbitrary method. You can either use `type` attribute to specify the class name (it will be instantiated by JSF) or `binding` attribute to give an instance of the object that you created by yourself (not a method!). The object must implement `javax.faces.event.ActionListener`.

Your second try (`testDeviceGroupController.prepareCreate(event)`) is wrong on many levels, but the crux is that the methods are called not to handle your action, but to create the `Actionlistener` instance.

You have a couple of options:

- the sanest one: just make a method that calls each of the target methods. Since they are on different beans, you can inject one into the other.
- if that doesn't work for you, you can create a method that creates a listener object.

Like this:

```
public ActionListener createActionListener() {
    return new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
            System.out.println("here I have both the event object, and access to the enclosing bean");
        }
    };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<h:commandButton>
    <f:actionListener binding="#{whateverBean.createActionListener()}"/>            
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: To make it clear, why <p:commandButton process="@this" actionListener="#{whateverBean.actionListenerMethod}" /> * working ? ( I used it before when I need only onebean ) It create listener object out-of-the-box and than call whateverBean.actionListenerMethod ?

Comment: @smolarek999: it works, because it is supposed to work like this and it is stated in the documentation! commandbutton's actionListenerMethod takes an EL of a method to call; and actionlisteners binding takes an EL of an ActionListener object. You cannot just guess that two things work the same just because the name is similar. Really, guessing is a bad, bad idea.

Comment: ROFL: the traditional approach of guess-how-it-works-using-bare-intuition-and-random-associations-then-act-surprised

Answer (score 0):

The `binding` attribute value needs to point to an object implementing `ActionListener` interface, not a method.

From the documentation of `f:actionListener`'s `bindig` attribute :

> Value binding expression that evaluates to an object that implements javax.faces.event.ActionListener.

A similar problem was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315341/i-get-errors-when-i-add-this-actionlistener/16317059#16317059).