# Why am I able to bind <f:actionListener> to an arbitrary method if it's not supported by JSF?

Tags: jsf, binding, actionlistener, el, methodexpression

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and JSF Mojarra 2.1.6.

I have the following Facelets page:

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink value="link">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{backingBean.someMethod(1)}"/>
  </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

And the following backing-bean:

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class BackingBean {
  public void someMethod(int i) {
    System.out.println("It was called: " + i);
  }
}
```

When I click the link, "Info: It was called: 1" appears in the console.

The documentation for `binding` reads:

> Library: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core, http://java.sun.com/jsf/core (Jsf Core)
>
> Tag: actionListener
>
> **binding**
>
> Value binding expression that evaluates to an *object* that implements javax.faces.event.ActionListener. [emphasis mine]

Also, the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374012/multiple-actionlisteners-in-jsf) states that it's not possible for an `f:actionListener` to call an arbitrary method.

Why is the backing bean method called if this isn't supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the consequence of the new EL 2.2 feature of calling a method in a value expression via the `#{bean.method()}` syntax instead of only referencing a property via the `#{bean.property}` syntax (which should indeed be of the exact type `ActionListener`). It wouldn't have worked in EL 2.1 or older and it would also not work when you remove the arguments and the parentheses. That document was written when EL 2.2 didn't exist (it's actually not modified as compared to [JSF 1.2 version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/actionListener.html) from May 2006; EL 2.2 was introduced December 2009). I however do agree that it needs an update on that part as it's confusing to starters.

The answer you found made its points based on the document, but the answerer however didn't seem to realize based on the question that while `binding="#{testController.nodeListener}"` failed, the `binding="#{testController.nodeListener(event)}"` **actually** worked. This only doesn't give you the opportunity to pass the `ActionEvent`. The answer was better if it suggested to just use `binding="#{testController.nodeListener()}"` instead and grab the event information in other way, such as by calling [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)) or even by passing `#{component}` as argument. Only if you really need to have a hand of it, of course.

```
<h:commandLink value="link">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{bean.someMethod(component)}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

```
public void someMethod(UIComponent component) {
    System.out.println("It was called on: " + component); // HtmlCommandLink
}
```

#### See also:

- [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el/)
- [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el/)
- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)